# How do we join on column of option in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

What if I join two ds with such an expression:

```
ds1.join(ds2, ds1("OptionCol") === ds2("NonOptionCol"))
```

As OptionCol is of type: Option[Int] and NonOptionCol is of type: Int?

I run a test locally it seems to be working but is this recommmended to do?

Should I always join on columns with the same datatype?

Comment: Nothing's stopping you to join columns having different datatypes as long as they are `type-castable` , spark takes care of conversions , and nevertheless you cast the mismatched column implicitly

Comment: oh thank you. that's what i am missing. Spark is doing implicit conversion for me.